# php format number string with hyphens

Tags: php

I am facing a problem I want to format a string with hyphens like this if any idea in php purely **12345-6789012-3** here is my number and have same length everytime

```
$number = "1234567890123";
```

Comment: There's nothing magic to do it for you, you'll have to write some code to extract substrings and rebuild with hyphens between them

Comment: What exactly have you tried to format the number?

Comment: https://eval.in/728629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function format($n){
  return substr($n, 0, 5)."-".substr($n,5,7)."-".substr($n,12,1);
}
print format("1234567890123");
```

Output:-https://eval.in/728634

Comment: FYI that last subst could just be `substr($n,-1)`

Answer (score 5):

Never used `vsprintf()` in an answer before:

```
$result = vsprintf('%s%s%s%s%s-%s%s%s%s%s%s%s-%s', str_split($number));
```

Comment: this once is great. i didn't knew it